# What is Michael Garibaldi's rank on Babylon 5?

Tags: babylon-5

The Earth Force Military tends to mix-and-match their ranks, but they're generally recognizable:

- Sinclair is a Commander
- Sheridan is a Captain
- Ivonava starts as a Lt. Commander and is promoted to Commander
- Franklin's father is a General
- Krantz is a Major

and so on. We see that Garibaldi is in EarthForce and must therefore have a rank, but he's only ever referred to as "Security Chief", which is his position.

What rank does he hold?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Michael's EarthForce rank is [Chief Warrant Officer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_warrant_officer).

> **Sheridan:** *This is Captain John J. Sheridan. Serial number XO7Y39-Alpha. Security code: obsidian.*
>
> **Ivanova:** *This is Commander Susan Ivanova. Serial number Z48M27-Epsilon. Security code: griffin.*
>
> **Michael Garibaldi:** *This is **Chief Warrant Officer** Michael Garibaldi. Serial number V17L98. Security code: peekaboo.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Ceremonies of Light and Dark](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Ceremonies_of_Light_and_Dark)</sup></sub>

Comment: SF writers have had a distressingly poor grasp of military rank ever since the post-WW2-era writers writers aged enough for the *Next Generation* of writers to appear...

Answer (score 15):

[He holds the rank of Chief Warrant Officer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Garibaldi) for the first four seasons. Then he works as Director of Covert Intelligence for the Interstellar Alliance.

Comment: And what episode is that specified in?